# Deploying multisite Drupal install with Capistrano?

Tags: git, drupal, deployment, capistrano

The problem I am having is whenever I deploy a Drupal site from a git repository, I have to log in to the server and change permissions on a ton of folders by hand. That is something I want to automate. I am considering Capistrano, which I heard great things about, but the downside is it creates several folders in the "sites" folder and that doesn't work out if you have a multisite Drupal installation like mine.

Is there a simple way of making Capistrano work with multisite Drupal installations? Can you recommend a better solution to deploying a multisite Drupal install with git?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [drush make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) file instead. In it you write down which Drupal you want and contrib modules etc. You can even add your custom modules from git repos (and other VCS).

drush make is an extension to drush, and I've been very happy with it. Works well with big projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did it worked finally ?

I used it like this:

```
before "deploy:symlink", :configure

desc "set rights"
task :configure do
  run "chown -R wwdata #{release_path}/sites/"
end
```